# Proving a basic form of monotone convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

**Problem:**

Definition 4.4 of *Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course* by Klenke says that

> If $f \colon \varOmega \to [0, \infty]$ is measurable, then we define the **integral** of $f$ with respect to $\mu$ by
> \begin{equation}
> \int f \, d\mu := \sup \bigl\{ I(g) \colon g \in \mathbb{E}^+, g \leq f \bigr\}
> \end{equation}

where $\mathbb{E}^+$ is the space of non-negative simple functions and $I \colon \mathbb{E}^+ \to [0, \infty]$ is such that $I(f) = \sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i \, \mu(A_i)$.

I know that for $f \in \mathbb{E}^+$, there is a sequence of non-negative simple functions $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ such that $f_n \uparrow f$. **I would like to convince myself that**

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n \, d\mu = \int f \, d\mu
\end{equation}

so that I can think of $\int f \, d\mu$ as the limit of the integrals of non-negative simple functions that approximate $f$.

My attempted proof that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n \, d\mu = \int f \, d\mu$ is shown below.

**Attempted Proof:**

I know that $f \leq g$ implies that $I(f) \leq I(g)$. This gives us a monotone increasing sequence $\left(I(f_n)\right)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ of real numbers. I know that
\begin{equation}
    \lim_{n \to \infty} I(f_n) = \sup \left\{ I(f_n) \colon n \in \mathbb N \right\}
\end{equation}
i.e. the sequence converges to its supremum (which may be infinite). It remains to show that $\sup \left\{ I(f_n) \colon n \in \mathbb N \right\} = \int f \, d\mu$.

By definition, $\int f \, d\mu := \sup \left\{ I(g) \colon g \in \mathbb{E}^+, g \leq f \right\}$. If $\sup \left\{ I(f_n) \colon n \in \mathbb N \right\} \neq \sup \left\{ I(g) \colon g \in \mathbb{E}^+, g \leq f \right\}$, then because $\left\{ I(f_n) \colon n \in \mathbb N \right\} \subset \left\{ I(g) \colon g \in \mathbb{E}^+, g \leq f \right\}$, we must have $\sup \left\{ I(f_n) \colon n \in \mathbb N \right\} < \sup \left\{ I(g) \colon g \in \mathbb{E}^+, g \leq f \right\}$.

Suppose this is true. Then there exists $g \in \mathbb{E}^+$, $g \leq f$ such that $\sup \left\{ I(f_n) \colon n \in \mathbb N \right\} < I(g)$. However, because $f_n \uparrow f$, we know that there exists an $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $g \leq f_n$. This implies that $I(g) \leq I(f_n)$, which implies that $\sup \left\{ I(f_n) \colon n \in \mathbb N \right\} < I(f_n)$, which is clearly a contradiction.